# Weird behavior with indexOf usingComparator

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, comparator, indexof

I'm trying to get the position of an object inside an array, and if the object is not there, i want to insert it. The weird thing is that the last "Copy" string is returning NSNotFound, and i just can't imagine why.

```
NSMutableArray *original = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *new = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[original addObject:@"Copy"];
[original addObject:@"Copy"];
[original addObject:@"Table"];
[original addObject:@"Table"];
[original addObject:@"Camper"];
[original addObject:@"Copy"];

for (NSString *string in original) {
    NSUInteger i = [new indexOfObject:string inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, [new count]) options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [obj1 compare:obj2];
    }];

    if (i == NSNotFound) {
        [new addObject:string];
    }

    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)i);
}
```

I know i can do it in other ways but i just want to understand whats wrong with that. This is the NSLog:

```
2147483647 (NSNotFound)
0
2147483647 (NSNotFound)
1
2147483647 (NSNotFound)
2147483647 (NSNotFound) WHY ?????
```

Comment: `indexOfObject:` will perform `[obj1 compare:obj2]`, so your use of comparator makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing the the method `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:`. That method should only be used on pre-sorted arrays, the array you're checking is not sorted. Your array is not sorted, since "Camper" would come before all of the other objects in that array. The `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:` has undefined behavior when you give it an unsorted array.

Here's the correct way to do what you want. There are other `NSArray` methods available for finding indexes, if you want to have different options or methods of determining equality.

```
NSMutableArray *original = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *new = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[original addObject:@"Copy"];
[original addObject:@"Copy"];
[original addObject:@"Table"];
[original addObject:@"Table"];
[original addObject:@"Camper"];
[original addObject:@"Copy"];

for (NSString *string in original) {
    NSUInteger i = [new indexOfObjectWithOptions:0 passingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [string compare:obj] == NSOrderedSame;
    }];

    if (i == NSNotFound) {
        [new addObject:string];
    }

    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)i);
}
```

See [NSArray documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject%3ainSortedRange%3aoptions%3ausingComparator%3a) for more information.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! But, what if i needed to use the comparator? Like comparing an attribute of an object to know if they are the same.

Comment: Just edited to show using a custom equality check. Comparators are only used for sorting (which you are not doing), but a block returning a BOOL for equality accomplishes what you want.

Comment: the most useless usage of a comparator ever, as `indexOfObject:` would call `[obj1 compare:obj2]` anyway. but OP whats it this way…

Comment: @vikingosegundo Actually i need this to compare real objects, i used a NSString in the question to make easier to understand. That's why i said that i needed to do it using the comparator!

Comment: Just change the `return [string compare:obj] == NSOrderedSame;` part to whatever comparison you want, like `return [someArray isEqualToArray:obj];`.

Comment: no, you should still not need a comparator to get the index, instead make sure the class implements caparison correctly.

Comment: There is no reason for a literal comparator block, as those are only used when sorting things. This exercise has absolutely no need for sorting. It only requires checking for "equality", which can be done through `isEqual:`, `compare:`, or any arbitrary method.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, i will try your solution as well, overriding isEqual, thanks ;)